# Is there in bash an array_combine function, where I can create an associative array from two?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, samba

I have two arrays one with user names and other with their full names that are actually dynamically generated by **wbinfo -u**.

```
USR=(user1 user2 user3)
FULL=("full user 1" "full user 2" "full user 3")
```

I want to create an associative array that I can use it with **pdbedit** so in the loop I would create/modify the user name and full name (in PHP would be easy using [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php)).

```
pdbedit -u $username -f $fullname
```

Comment: FYI, all-uppercase names are reserved for environment variables and shell builtins; honoring this convention prevents namespace collisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this yourself using only bash 4.3 built-ins ([and no `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)) as follows:

```
combine() {
  declare key_no key val
  declare -n _keys=$1 _vals=$2 _dest=$3
  declare -g -A "$3"
  for key_no in "${!_keys[@]}"; do
    key=${_keys[$key_no]}
    val=${_vals[$key_no]}
    _dest[$key]=$val
  done
}

usr=(user1 user2 user3)
full=("full user 1" "full user 2" "full user 3")

combine usr full arr
```

This version goes through some extra paranoia to work correctly with sparse arrays.

---

If you need to support versions of bash prior to 4.3 (and, ideally, late-series 4.3, as there are security bugs impacting namevar support which could lead to arbitrary code execution in early 4.3 releases), then the following code uses `declare` to be somewhat more cautious (thanks to [Glenn Jackman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) for suggesting this solution over the prior approach here, which used `eval` carefully):

```
combine() {
  declare keys_var=$1 vals_var=$2 result_var=$3
  declare indirect i keys
  declare -gA "$result_var"

  indirect="${keys_var}[@]"; keys=( "${!indirect}" )
  for (( i=0; i < ${#keys[@]}; i++ )); do
    indirect="${vals_var}[$i]"; declare -g "${result_var}[${keys[i]}]=${!indirect}"
  done
}
```

Comment: Thank you. the second method worked for me as my bash version is 4.2.37 in one and 4.3.30 in the other machine.

Comment: Glad this helped! BTW, I just took another look and realized I'd been a bit sloppy about declaring local variables; both versions should be better about that now (no longer leaking `key` and `val` into global scope).

Comment: ...and the second version is updated again using a far better approach suggested by @glenn-jackman.

Comment: It's working, BUT, when I run the for loop it all the items of each array as one item. So all the names in **usr** is treated as one name, the same happens with **full**. I could guess it's because the quotes but even surrounding with quotes using **awk** the result is the same.

Comment: The problem seems to be obtaining dynamically the arrays. When I use `cat /smbexport/list-users.txt | awk -F"\n" '{print "\""$1$2"\""}' | tr '\n' ' ' /scripts/combine.sh` the loop works.

Comment: If you use `declare -p usr` and `declare -p full`, does it show them as arrays containing multiple distinct items? If not, I'd suggest asking a new question focused on how you're populating those arrays, with enough details to reproduce the issue. Feel free to put a link to it here; I'd be curious to see said question!

Comment: The second array isn't being treated as array when obtained dynamically.

Comment: @tenshimsm, that depends, of course, on exactly how you're "obtaining" it -- which is why I suggested asking a separate question focused around that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no readymade **array combine** routine but you can cheat it this way:

```
USR=(user1 user2 user3)
FULL=("full user 1" "full user 2" "full user 3")

declare -A arr
eval "$(paste -d= <(printf 'arr[%q]\n' "${USR[@]}") <(printf '%q\n' "${FULL[@]}"))
```

**Test it:**

```
declare -p arr
declare -A arr='([user3]="full user 3" [user2]="full user 2" [user1]="full user 1" )'
```

Comment: Is this safe in the case of contents containing literal `$()` and the like?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, this is not safe at all. Could be fixed with `eval "$(paste -d= <(printf 'arr[%q]\n' "${USR[@]}") <(printf '%q\n' "${FULL[@]}"))`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thanks so much, I see your important point. I should have used `%q` instead of `%s` with quotes in `eval`.